How to find Maximum value and its position in a column vector in MathCAD15?
I am trying to write a simple function in mathcad 15 to find the maximum value and its position in a column vector and return the maximum value and position in a 2x1 vector.
The image is the vector column I am using:

This is the function I wrote in MathCAD 15

The function isn't outputing the correction position, it only finds the maximum value and doesn't bring the correct position. With trial and error I figured out that max1 isn't updating and the position is always giving me the original value of the initialized max1.

How can I fix this problem? What do I need to do to make the function print the maximum value and its correct position?

Let Xi>max0 in the first comparison, then your function updates max0 to Xi
Consequently, Xi is no longer greater than max0 in the second comparison and max1 does not get updated.
